# How to check (select) element in ARIA-menuitemcheckbox (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-automation

I have the following HTML item (menubox):

```
<div class="uiContextualLayerPositioner uiLayer" data-testid="undefined" data-ownerid="u_0_10" style="width: 473px; left: 288px; top: 290px;">
   <div class="uiContextualLayer _5v-0 _53il uiContextualLayerBelowLeft">
      <div class="_54nq _57di _558b _2n_z" id="u_0_y">
         <div class="_54ng">
            <ul class="_54nf" role="menu">
               <li class="_54ni _5ipo __MenuItem" role="presentation">
                  <a class="_54nc _54nu" href="#" role="menuitemcheckbox">
                  <span>
                  <i class="mrs img sp_Kw8-3yVLtZo sx_864bd8"></i>
                  <span class="_54nh">Item1</span>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class="_54ni _5ipo _54nd __MenuItem" role="presentation">
                  <a class="_54nc _54nu" href="#" data-testid="notif_setting_higlights" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="true">
                  <span>
                  <i class="mrs img sp_Kw8-3yVLtZo sx_864bd8">
                  </i>
                  <span class="_54nh">Item2</span>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class="_54ni _5ipo __MenuItem" role="presentation">
                  <a class="_54nc _54nu" href="#" role="menuitemcheckbox">
                  <span>
                  <i class="mrs img sp_Kw8-3yVLtZo sx_864bd8"></i>
                  <span class="_54nh">Item3</span>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class="_54ni _5ipo __MenuItem" role="presentation">
                  <a class="_54nc _54nu" href="#" role="menuitemcheckbox">
                  <span>
                  <i class="mrs img sp_ey5BbZl6hUH sx_780712">
                  </i>
                  <span class="_54nh">Item4</span>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and i can see that Item1 is deselected, and Item2 is selected with:

```
aria-checked="true"
```

and i want to deselect Item2 and select Item1. For this purpose take objectID from Item1 that says it's selected

```
_54nc _54nu
```

and call

```
document.getElementById("_54nc _54nu").setAttribute("aria-checked", true)', 'about: blank', 0)
```

but nothin happens. What did i missed?

P.S. I see that all object-ID's of class are same, but i also tried other id's. Maybe I misunderstood the issue of id for the class, and maybe the way it is different. Please give me directions. :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` is incorrect since none of your element has any `id`.
You want to use `document.getElementsByClassName()`